# ASP.NET - How can I check all checkboxes across gridview pages at once and access checked rows in a gridview across pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, paging

I have a gridview which allows you to download the files of the rows you checked. It downloads the files into a .zip file. Everything works fine except for two things:

1. If I select "check all", it only checks all in the first page of the gridview. If there's enough data to have more than one page, how can I make it so the check-all actually selects ALL?
2. If I have checked boxes across different pages and I click a button that is supposed to download all the files, it only downloads the files of the page that I'm currently viewing. So if I'm viewing gridview page 2, and I download the checked rows, it will only download the files I have checked in page 2 -- even if I have checked boxes in page 1.

Here's my code:

Checkbox and Gridview:

```
 private void RemoveRowIndex(int index)
        {

            SelectedShotIndex.Remove(index);

        }

        private void PersistRowIndex(int index)
        {
            if (!SelectedShotIndex.Exists(i => i == index))
            {
                SelectedShotIndex.Add(index);
            }
        }

        private List<Int32> SelectedShotIndex
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState[SELECTED_SHOT_INDEX] == null)
                {
                    ViewState[SELECTED_SHOT_INDEX] = new List<Int32>();
                }

                return (List<Int32>)ViewState[SELECTED_SHOT_INDEX];
            }
        }

        private void RePopulateCheckBoxes()
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.Rows)
            {
                var chkBox = row.FindControl("chkShot") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;

                IDataItemContainer container = (IDataItemContainer)chkBox.NamingContainer;

                if (SelectedShotIndex != null)
                {
                    if (SelectedShotIndex.Exists(i => i == container.DataItemIndex))
                    {
                        chkBox.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void gvSearchResultsUserAdmin_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

            if (Session["gvSearchResultsUserAdmin"] != null)
            {
                gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.DataSource = Session["gvSearchResultsUserAdmin"];
            }
            else
            {
                //gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.DataSource = ds;

            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.Rows)
            {
                var chkBox = row.FindControl("chkShot") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;

                IDataItemContainer container = (IDataItemContainer)chkBox.NamingContainer;

                if (chkBox.Checked)
                {
                    PersistRowIndex(container.DataItemIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveRowIndex(container.DataItemIndex);
                }
            }
            LoadGridView();
            //gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.DataBind();
            RePopulateCheckBoxes(); 
        }
```

Select all checkbox:

```
 protected void chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox ChkBoxHeader = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkboxSelectAll");
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.Rows)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkShot");
                    if (ChkBoxHeader.Checked == true)
                    {
                        ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ChkBoxRows.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                }
            }
        }
```

My "Download All" Button:

```
    protected void btnDownloadShots_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvSearchResultsUserAdmin.Rows)
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chk = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkShot");
                    if (chk.Checked)
                    {
                        SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand();
                        try
                        {
                            filmName = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
                            shotNumber = int.Parse(gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                        objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        objcmd.CommandText = "ShotIDfromSearch";

                        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filmName", filmName);
                        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shotNumber", shotNumber);
                        ds = objdb.getDataSetUsingCmdObj(objcmd);

                        shotID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<int>("ShotID");

                        FilePath = ReturnFilePath(shotID);
                        //Response.ForceDownload(FilePath, filmName + " - Shot " + shotNumber.ToString() + ".mp4");

                        zip.AddFile(FilePath, filmName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }


            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Vertov.zip");
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this is to store it first the details in a cache or other alternative storage (checked data) and from there you can pull out the details from cache perhaps to download the files.